# Instalação GxServer 15 x Windows server 2008 SP2

Tags: genexus

Não estou conseguindo instalar o GxServer 15.
Esta Maquina já possui outras instancias do Ev3 em execução.
Segui o wiki, de requerimentos, já instalei o dotNet 4.6

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claudio,

O setup está com problema. Precisará baixar um setup com build >= a 107481.

Baixar desde o preview do U1 neste link:

"https://www.genexus.com/developers/DownloadCenter?en,,,4978;;"

Para referência,  o requerimento do GeneXus V15 está aqui: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30900,GeneXus%2015%20hardware%20and%20software%20requirements

Paulo

Comment: Vou aguardar a liberação! Obrigado!

Comment: Claudio,

No dia 19 tem um build de número 107493 para o setup do GXServer.
Então acredito que você já possa tentar rodar no seu WIndows 2008 SP2 e terá sucesso..

Paulo

Comment: testado e instalado com sucesso! obrigado